# Good data structure to represent a 2D map/grid that you can zoom in and out of?

Tags: java, data-structures, grid, 2d, zooming

I've built a 2D grid in java where each cell can have a certain attribute, say color. At each iteration of the main loop, that color can possibly change.

What I want to be able to do:
 - when zoomed in, it will show a small subset of the grids and the actual color of each grid.
 - as you zoom out and see more cells at once, the cells will start to get too small to be seen individually, so I want to be able to just represent that area(a collection of cells) as a single color (say the most often occurring one in that collection)

One thing I thought of for doing this would be to use a hierarchical tree/pyramid structure, where at the leaves you have each cell. Each parent node contains summary information of each of its children. So to draw the map at a high zoom level, I'd only need to go down a few levels in the tree instead of looking at each cell individually. However, propagation of changes from leaves to parents and subsequently to each higher level seems like it'd take quite awhile in a large grid for every loop iteration.

Is there a better way to do this? This problem seems like it should have been handled before by people in the graphics/gaming world but I'm having trouble even finding the right keywords to Google, so any help or direction is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So the colour of each small cell can change in each iteration? Please elaborate on what is changed and how (is it random). Also: is the detail level of the map the same in each place?

Comment: It's basically a creature simulator. Each creature inhabits a cell and can move around every turn. Their movement pattern is dictated by a behavior/decision component which can be somewhat random. What I'd like to do is to be able to zoom all the way out and show the whole map with regions shaded according to the color of the most dominant species in that area.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps quadtree would be a helpful search term.

http://www.google.com/m/url?client=safari&ei=idePTdD_LuWJiAKbgM3pAQ&hl=en&oe=UTF-8&q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree&ved=0CBMQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNEjIDTtDl-nIhlMVz6WemoQ_w8jYg

Comment: Ooh..quadtrees! Hadn't thought of that. Might not work for the creature display since that changes pretty frequently but I might try using a quadtree for the more static terrain/foliage. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track.  What you propose is a typical implementation of a 2D scene graph and determining bounds of parent nodes.

Keep in mind that even though leaf nodes might change colors, the change may not be propogated all the way up due to previous state.  What you need to be sure to do is track dirty leaves so you don't do the update for everything when its not necessary.

I think you should implement what you propose and then see if performance is really an issue.  How many cells are in your grid?

Comment: Hm..that makes sense. I might not need to repaint at every loop in some cases. Delaying and batching update propagations seems like it might help reduce some busywork. I'm trying to make it as big as it can go. So far I've only tried it with about 500x500 cells, but it starts to lag because I currently just paint everything, even though the colors don't show up correctly at high zoom(due to aliasing). Thanks for the suggestion.